# Different background color for different pages in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, background, styling

So I'm using an application.html.erb file which is basically the layout for every page in my website. But I want the homepage to have a white background and the rest of the pages to have a different background. The problem is, if I wrap the entire homepage file in a div, it only wraps the "yield" place and so it shows as a box with a white background within a larger box with a gray background. So how can I change the entire background of the homepage and leave the rest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Expanding on the answer provided by @muffinista:
You can use an instance variable set in the controller to determine when to put the 'homepage' class on the body tag. So:

```
def index
  @home_page = true
  # existing code
end
```

and in the layout:

```
<body class="<%= @home_page ? 'homepage' : ''%>">
 <%= yield %>
</body>
```

Comment: What do I put after homepage?  `<body class="<%= @home_page ? 'homepage' : 'background-color: #000'%>">` ?

Comment: @evan In the answer, if it's not a homepage, you don't put anything there (hence the empty string). If you want to use some other class for all other pages, that class could go there. You should not put style information there, both because style should be in style sheets, and because that part of the code is specifically for adding classes.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus edit to my deleted post: what is `home` doing and why doesn't `black` work as the class? `<body class="<%= @home ? 'home' : "black" %>">`

Comment: @evan `home` is a class. `@home` is an instance variable. I don't see anything wrong with your code, assuming that 'black' is a class. Perhaps you should ask a new question with your specific case - this seems beyond the scope of a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Consider putting a special class on the body tag (or perhaps your main wrapper) of your homepage, then do it in CSS.  So you can have on your homepage:

```
<body class="homepage">
  <p>hi!</p>
</body>
```

Then on your other pages:

```
<body>
  <p>i am not a homepage!</p>
</body>
```

And in your CSS:

```
body {
 // some general css
}

body.homepage {
 // some css for homepage elements
 background-color: #000000;
}
```

**UPDATE**: you can use a helper like this to make life easier:

```
def body_class
  @body_class || ''
end
```

Then in your homepage views, put something like this at the top:

```
<% @body_class = "homepage" %>
```

Obviously this depends on the specifics of your app, but it works fine for me.

Comment: The problem is, the homepage doesn't have a body. All the HTML from the homepage goes as the yield to a template application.html.erb which only has one body...Can i have a body within a body?

Comment: You could also use `content_for` to add javascript in the head to change the class of body if you want to modify this in the view. (Generic way to modify the layout without modifying the layout)

Comment: @NosayrYassin I just added some details to my answer for how I do this -- in short, there's a helper that will make this easier for you. This is generally how people set page titles, etc, as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the accepted answer, if you need to set different backgrounds for multiple pages, it would make sense and add readability to move the code for finding an appropriate background into a partial:

`<body class= <%=render partial: "layouts/background" %> >`

_background.html.erb:

```
    <%- if @main_page_background OR @stylish_background %>
       "main_page_background"
      <%- elsif @dark_background %>   
        "dark_page_background"
      <%- else %>  
        ""  
    <% end %>
```