# How do I get my Rails app background image to show up correctly?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have one page in a Rails app that I want to render a background image on (I'll call it "glow.jpg"), and have been struggling getting it work properly. (The other pages have a simple pattern background that shows up fine. Done with:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("pixel_weave.png");
}
```

in my application.css.scss file.

I have searched all over and the best I've been able to do is get glow.jpg to show up across the top of the page (in about the exact size/location as a jumbotron - I'm also using Bootstrap, btw), with the bottom portion of the image cutoff. I've tried `background: image-url('glow.jpg')`, `background-image: url('glow.jpg')`, and a few others. The image path is assets/images.

Recently I separated the css for this homepage (which will have the glow.jpg bg) into it's own file, homepages.css.scss here:

```css
html body .intro-header {
  background: url("glow.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}


.intro-header {

  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

And here is the html.erb:

```html
<% content_for(:title, "Concert | Home") %>

<div class="intro-header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="intro-message">
          <h1>Welcome Home</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Right now, the intro-header shows up, but with only the h1 and no image.

One more of note; I have an application.html.erb file that renders a header partial on every page (which I want on the homepage as well), which is just a navbar. I have wondered if it might be conflicting at all?

EDIT: Rails v 4.1.5. And here's a screenshot. Basically, I want the background pattern that is there to be replaced by another image, filling the entire page below the navbar.[image]

Thanks for your help! Please let me know if I can provide any more info.

Comment: Which version of rails are you using?

Comment: Also, can you mock up an image of what it is you're trying to do? It's a little hard to grasp just from the explanation.

Comment: @MattD I included a screenshot of the page currently. Please let me know if I can explain further. Thanks

Comment: So the background in that image is what you want on all the pages except the home page?

Comment: No, sorry that's what it is for all other pages. On that page, I want a different image, glow.jpg.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different background color for different pages in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882828/different-background-color-for-different-pages-in-rails)

Comment: thanks @MattD, that might be the solution. However, I don't understand part of the answer and since I don't have 50 reputation, I can't comment there. How can I get clarification on an answer to someone else's question?

Comment: Does 50 rep let you chat in the chatrooms? Could try there.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the tip from @mattD, I was able to get it working based on the answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882828/different-background-color-for-different-pages-in-rails) To summarize - In my "homepages" controller I now have:

`def index
    @homepage_class = true
 end`

And in application.html.erb:

`<body class="<%= @homepage_class ? 'homepage' : ''%>">`

I defined `body.homepage` in the application.css.scss file and added it to the body tag of the page I want the background on.